# Elasticsearch: Constant score applied within match query, but after search terms have been analysed?

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I have some documents, with the following values contained within a text field called `name`

- Document1: `abc xyz group`
- Document2: `group x/group y`
- Document3: `group 1, group 2, group 3, group 4`

Now imagine I'm sending a simple match query to ES for the term 'group':

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "group"
        }
    }
}
```

My desired outcome would be that all 3 documents would return with the same score, no matter how often the term appears, where it appears, etc.
Now, **I already know that I can do this** by wrapping my `match` with a `constant_score`, like so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "match": {
                    "name": "group"
                }
            },
            "boost": 1
        }            
    }
}
```

BUT, say I now want to query using the search term `abc group`. In this case, what I want to happen is that Document2 and Document3 will return the same score (matches `group`), but Document1 to have a better score as it matches both `abc` and `group`.

With a `constant_score` wrapping my `match` query, documents that contain any of the terms return the same score (i.e Document1, 2 and 3 return the same score for `abc group`). If I remove the `constant_score`, then Document 3 has the best score presumably because it contains more matches with the search text (`group` appearing 4 times).

It seems as though I need a way of moving the `constant_score` query to after the `match` query has analyzed my search text. Effectively causing a query of `abc group` to be two `constant_score` queries - one for `abc` and one for `group`.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by utilising Elasticsearch's `unique` token filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html

I've added that to my `name` field in the index mappings, and it looks to be retrieving the desired results without having to worry about `constant_score`.

Note however all this does is eliminate term frequencies from having any effect on the `_score` - other metrics (such as `fieldLength`) still have an effect on the results. This isn't, therefore, the equivalent of using a post-analyzed version of `constant_score` as I hypothesized in the question, however this will suffice for my current requirements.